# How do I get a cases-like environment with a right brace?

Tags: itemize, unicode-math, cases

I want these braces like this, and I tried it out..Maybe it was wrong how I tried it in LaTeX? [image]

LaTeX Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Anpassung des Zeichensatzs (Sonderzeichen)
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{rcases}
     \begin{aligned}
     \begin{itemize}
         \item g \parallel E \;:\;\text{Abstand} d \neq 0
         \item g \subset E \;:\;\text{Abstand} d = 0
     \end{itemize}
     \end{aligned}
   \end{rcases}\Rightarrow \begin{rcases}
        E: \langle \vv{n},\vv{r}-\vv{r}_0 \rangle = 0\\ g: \vv{r}(t)=\vv{r}_1+t\vv{a}, \; t \in R
   \end{rcases}\Rightarrow \text{Skalarprodukt:} \langle \vv{n},\vv{a} \rangle \\
```

Comment: I wouldn't use LaTeX for a cheat sheet. On the other hand, considering your handwriting ... I would still do the task by hand not using LaTeX. Far too much fumbling around with this kind of stuff.

Comment: My LaTeX document is 73 sites long. And I want this in LaTeX. So please help me or don't. its still my decision :)

Comment: (Side note: It is "pages" not "sites".)

Comment: ah right, sorry i am a german..there is no difference in german language. i forgot xD

Comment: Nice question. I've proposed a new title that would be easier for anyone else with a similar question to find in a search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a quick and inelegant attempt. Which engine do you use (I am asking because you load `inputenc` (usually used for non-unicode, hence `pdfLaTeX`) and `unicode-math` (usually for unicode, hence `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`)? I am not sure whether you want to use the arrows `⇒` or not. They are not seen in the image but in your source code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage{fontspec}%new
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Anpassung des Zeichensatzs (Sonderzeichen)
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}%I guess this does not fit to inputenc
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{dsfont}%new for blackboard bold R in Latin Modern.


\newcommand{\bulletspace}{\bullet\hspace{0.5ex}}%new
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\innerprod[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1,#2}%new. This makes stuff easier. You already loaded mathtools. 
\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
    \begin{rcases}
    \parbox[c]{10.7em}{
        %You may work with the itememize as an alternative. 
        %\begin{itemize}
            %\item 
            $\bulletspace g \parallel E \colon\text{Abstand } d \neq 0$\\
            %\item 
            $\bulletspace g \subset E\colon \text{Abstand } d = 0$
        %\end{itemize}
    }
    \end{rcases}
    \Rightarrow%This is not shown in image
    \begin{rcases}
    \parbox[c]{11.5em}{
        $E\colon \innerprod{\vv{n}}{\vv{r}-\vv{r}_0} = 0$\\ 
    $g\colon \vv{r}(t)=\vv{r}_1+t\vv{a}, \; t \in \mathds R  $ % you might want to use a different font for the real numbers like \mathbf R or \BbbR or ℝ
    }
    \end{rcases}
    \Rightarrow%This is not shown in image
    \parbox[c]{7em}{
        {Skalarprodukt:} \\
        $\innerprod{\vv{n}}{\vv{a}}=0 $
    }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use ShareLateX :o thank you for your help! I try this out

Comment: it works, thanks! and thanks a lot for commenting this! :D

Comment: You are very welcome. In case this is a cheat sheet: Good luck on your exams.

Comment: My Professor allows to bring all the sites with us in the exam we wrote. So i'm doing this. My compiler is XeLaTeX, you can choose it in ShareLaTeX :D

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution that sets up a dedicated `array`-like environment called `rarray`. It uses two instance of `rarray` and one instance of `array`. (Aside: The `array` environment is very basic, but also very flexible and powerful, environment.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}  % for \uline macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l} % automatic display-style mode
\newenvironment{rarray}{%
   \left.\begin{array}{L @{{}:{}} L @{} }}{%
   \end{array}\right\} }

\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\mdseries\noindent\uline} % optional

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{subsection}{9}

\subsection{Lagebeziehungen von einer Gerade und \dots}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{rarray}
\bullet\ g\parallel E & \text{Abstand $d\ne0$} \\
\bullet\ g<E          & \text{Abstand $d=0$} % g<E ??
\end{rarray}
\begin{rarray}
 E & \langle \vec{n},\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0 \rangle\\
 g & \vec{r}(t)=\vec{r}_1+t\cdot\vec{a},\ t\in\mathbb{R}
\end{rarray}
\begin{array}{c}
\text{Skalarprodukt:}\\
\langle\vec{n},\vec{a}\rangle=0
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```